# BigQuery Date and Time Functions returning NULL on a timestamp column

Tags: google-bigquery

I am pulling 3 timestamp columns: timestamp, prev_timestamp, next_timestamp from one timestamp column in a table using LAG() and LEAD().  I need to do some simple date & time formatting but when I use a function like MONTH() on either prev_timestamp or next_timestamp it returns NULL.

The schema type of the resulting column is correct (TIMESTAMP) and for some reason regular timestamp date and time formatting works.  How do I make it so that it returns the month correctly for all 3 columns?

Example code that returns the month for timestamp column and NULL for prev and next timestamp columns:

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(timestamp) AS month,
  MONTH(prev_timestamp) AS prev_month,
  MONTH(next_timestamp) AS next_month
FROM (
  SELECT
    timestamp,
    LAG(timestamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) prev_timestamp,
    LEAD(timestamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) next_timestamp
  FROM timestamp_table
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So having tested and checked a couple of things, I actually inspired myself from [Mikhail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472714/bigquery-date-and-time-functions-returning-null-on-a-timestamp-column/32481952#32481952) and realized his answer is incorrect, since the lag/lead doesn't return milliseconds, but MICROseconds (why? that's anybody's guess).

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(timestamp) AS month,
  MONTH(MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP((prev_timestamp/1000))) AS prev_month,
  MONTH(MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP((next_timestamp/1000))) AS next_month
FROM (
  SELECT
    timestamp,
    LAG(timestamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) prev_timestamp,
    LEAD(timestamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) next_timestamp
  FROM timestamp_table
  )
```

Should work. I just tested creating a table with three rows that are timestamp. Using this without the /1000, my lagged/lead versions were giving a different month. I tested and turns out, if you don't do the division, you end up somewhere in the 47th millennium.

Comment: This look to have worked - I'm still curious about why this works though.  What am I not understanding about the typecast that makes us have to convert from MSEC and when did that happen?

Comment: @AaronR I'm not entirely sure as to the why, but I think that internally, to save space, timestamps are saved as "microsecs since epoch". The "Lead" and "Lag" functions probably return them "format-less" forcing us to use that workaround

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)) AS month,
  MONTH(MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(prev_timestamp)) AS prev_month,
  MONTH(MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(next_timestamp)) AS next_month
FROM (
  SELECT
    timestamp,
    LAG(timestamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) prev_timestamp,
    LEAD(timestamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) next_timestamp
  FROM timestamp_table
  )
```

Comment: Trying this with Timestamps in (I made a "select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()" as my test table) gives a type error... not sure this is the solution here. GOT IT, forget it. You don't need the MSEC for the first timestamp, as it returns a timestamp indeed. It's the other ones that require the change